# Linq query to array

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects

This is currently my Linq query:

```
result = From d In dc.Tracker
   Where d.Responsible.Value = "first last name"
      Order By d.Priority1, d.Deadline
   Select New With { _
      Key .Title = d.Name, _
      Key .Description = d.Priority1, _
      Key .Priority2= d.Priority2, _
      Key .Status = d.Status, _
      Key .Resp= d.Resp, _
      Key .Deadline = d.Deadline, _
      Key .Notes = d.Notes, _
   }
```

I am trying to output the data but can only seem to do so doing this:

```
For Each d In result
   Console.WriteLine(d)
Next
```

But i can not seem to place it into an array so that i can call it like this:

```
result(0), result(1), etc etc...
```

Or even better:

```
result.Title, result.Description, etc etc...
```

How can i change that linq into an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working at least how i am needing it too:

```
Dim Title As New ArrayList
Dim Description As New ArrayList
Dim Priority2 As New ArrayList
Dim Status As New ArrayList
Dim Resp As New ArrayList
Dim Deadline As New ArrayList
Dim Notes As New ArrayList

result = From d In dc.Tracker
   Where d.Responsible.Value = "first last name"
      Order By d.Priority1, d.Deadline
   Select New With { _
      Key .Title = d.Name, _
      Key .Description = d.Priority1, _
      Key .Priority2= d.Priority2, _
      Key .Status = d.Status, _
      Key .Resp= d.Resp, _
      Key .Deadline = d.Deadline, _
      Key .Notes = d.Notes, _
   }

For Each d In result
    If Not IsNothing(d.Title()) Then Title.Add(d.Title()) Else Title.Add("NA")
    If Not IsNothing(d.Description()) Then Description.Add(d.Description().value) Else Description.Add("NA")
    If Not IsNothing(d.Priority2()) Then Cost.Add(d.Priority2().value) Else Priority2.Add("NA")
    If Not IsNothing(d.Status()) Then Status.Add(d.Status().value) Else Status.Add("NA")
    If Not IsNothing(d.Resp()) Then Responsible.Add(d.Resp().value) Else Resp.Add("NA")
    If Not IsNothing(d.Deadline()) Then Deadline.Add(d.Deadline()) Else Deadline.Add("NA")
    If Not IsNothing(d.Notes()) Then Notes.Add(d.Notes()) Else Notes.Add("NA")
Next
```

Comment: I'd be interested to know why you need it like this. Looks like hacking around a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.ToArray()` method.

```
result = (From d In dc.Tracker
          Where d.Responsible.Value = "first last name"
          Order By d.Priority1, d.Deadline
          Select New With { _
           .Title = d.Name, _
           .Description = d.Priority1, _
           .Priority2= d.Priority2, _
           .Status = d.Status, _
           .Resp= d.Resp, _
           .Deadline = d.Deadline, _
           .Notes = d.Notes}).ToArray()
```

Comment: **An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException' occurred in Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll**

Comment: I don't think your query was set up right so I adjusted it.

Comment: Its setup just the way you have it here.

Comment: Did you see the change I made?

Comment: What type of object is `dc.Tracker`?

Comment: Ok, but what type of object is it? `EF`, `POCO`?

Comment: **Global.System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery(Of TrackerItem)**

Comment: Did you check the `dc.Tracker` object to see if it returned the values expected, before this query on it?

Comment: Yes. Like i said, it works using console.write() instead of debug.print to output the returned values. I just don't know how to access them via a array to pull just stuff i need.